# Displaying a checkbox only for the shows(in the tvshow table) that don't match the entries for a given user id in the watchedtvshow table - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is what I want to do:
Display a checkbox for the tvshow field entry(from the tvshow table) only if that field entry doesn't match the entries for a given user id in the 'watchedtvshow' table

Table structure for 'tvshow':
id tvshow

Table structure for 'watchedtvshow'
id uid tvid(id of the tvshow)

Here is my controller method:

```
$tvshow = TVShow::with('watchedtvshow')->get();  
return View::make('browse',['tvshow' => $tvshow]);
```

My View:

```
@foreach($tvshow as $show)
   {{ $show->title }} {{ 'a checkbox' }}  
@endforeach
```

What I tried:
In my controller method:

```
$tvshow = TVShow::with('watchedtvshow')->get();

$uid = NULL;
if(Auth::check())
$uid = Auth::user()->id;

return View::make('browse',[
   'tvshow' => $tvshow,
   'uid' => $uid,
]);
```

In my view:

```
@foreach($tvshow as $show)
    {{ $show->title }}
    @foreach($show->watchedtvshow as $watchedtvshow)
        @if($watchedtvshow->uid == $uid)
            {{'don't show checkbox'}}
        @else
            {{'show checkbox'}}
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The problem:
The thing is the second foreach loop executes only for the times it finds a watched tv show, otherwise it doesn't. So it just won't show any checkboxes.

I'm not an experienced coder, haven't really encountered anything like this before, I've spent three whole days trying to solve this, using count, for loops and what not, but I can't. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: I suspect the issue is in your fetching the data from the model - have you checked that you are happy with the data in `$tvshow`? You can temporarily add a `foreach` loop in your controller to output it (the output will be messy, but since it is temporary, that's fine).

Comment: I don't follow what you want your query to do, and since you've only mentioned it in the title, I wonder if you would add a fuller explanation into the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off a quick pointer: you can get the logged-in user's ID with `Auth::id()` rather than having to set it to null, then check if they're logged in then get the id directly off the model.

As for your problem, you're quite right that using the code you have you won't be getting the full story. What you need to do is get a list of all TV shows (regardless of user having it) and additionally a list of all TV shows the user has seen. Now, you can do this many ways, but the best 'Laravel way' is to model the relationship between User and TVShow. Your code doesn't mention this so I won't assume you have already done it. Your database is, of course, already set up for this so all you need to do is create the relationship. In this case, the relationship you need is a `belongsToMany` (a user can 'have' (have watched) many shows, and a show can 'have' (have been watched by) many users:

```
// in User.php
public function shows()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('TVShow', 'watchedtvshow', 'uid', 'tvid');
}

// in TVShow.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'watchedtvshow', 'tvid', 'uid');
}
```

Once you have this you can get a list of all users that have watched a show with:

```
$show->users;
```

Or you can get a list of all shows a user has watched with:

```
$user->shows;
```

Now putting that all together you should use Laravel's collections to detect whether a given item if in both arrays:

```
// in the controller:
$shows = TVShow::all();

if (Auth::check()) {
    $watched = Auth::user()->shows;
} else {
    // just create an empty collection so we can assume a consistent API
    $watched = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection;
}

return View::make('browse', compact('shows', 'watched'));

// in browse.blade.php
@foreach($shows as $show)
    {{ $show->title }}

    @if ($watched->contains($show)
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    @else
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Something like that?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. You're awesome! I have so much to learn, I didn't even know you could do that. Thank you so much :) And also thanks for that pointer. This shows me that my previous code could have been a lot simpler and shorter.

Comment: No problem at all. There's a lot of info crammed into the Laravel documentation and it takes a few reads to take it all in to be honest. It'd also do you well to have a look through the [API docs](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/) too, especially for things like the `\Illuminate\Support'Collection` and `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` classes as they're central to the ORM but aren't really discussed much in the docs (actually it's better than it was when I was learning). Also, you may find reading the actual code is handy too when the docs/API docs don't provide enough info.